# Can't create column in SQLite Android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem like this:

> /SQLiteLog: (1) table ds_sinhvien has no column named id
>
> E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=An id=1 class=MMTT2011
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table ds_sinhvien has no
>   column named id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   ds_sinhvien(name,id,class) VALUES (?,?,?)

I don't know how to fix this, this is my dbhelper:

```
public class StudentDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbStudent";
    private static final String TB_STUDENT = "ds_sinhvien";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_CLASS = "class";
    public StudentDbHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// tạo table
        String SQL_String = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s(%sINTEGER PRIMARY KEY, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", TB_STUDENT,KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_CLASS);
        db.execSQL(SQL_String);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_STUDENT);
// Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void insertStudent(Student student)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String nullColumnHack = null; // Allow null value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        if (student.getId() != -1)
        {
            values.put(KEY_ID, student.getId());
            values.put(KEY_NAME, student.getName());
            values.put(KEY_CLASS, student.getClassName());
            db.insert(TB_STUDENT, null, values);
        }
        db.close();
    }
```

Thanks for helping me, i've tried to fix it for a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> %sINTEGER
> ```

This makes the column name `idINTEGER`. Add the missing space between the name and type. You can then uninstall your app to delete the old database with this incorrect column name and make `onCreate()` execute again.